# Html table CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Common

```
table tr td
{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Custom

```
table.custom tr td
{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

When I use like this:

```
<table class="custom">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>this text align top, but I want to align middle
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

sub table behave like its parent. How can ignore parent element style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you can do is adding the child selectors like so:

```
table.custom > tr > td { }
```

Then only the immediate children will match the style

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `>` indicator to only target direct child elements

```
table.custom > tr > td
{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

However it should be noted that using a `table` within a `table` is generally not a good idea.
Note 2: this will not work in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

`table.custom tr td` will select children at any level. The following DOM chains will all match

```
table.custom->tr->td
table.custom->tr->foo->td
table.custom->foo->tr->bar->td
```

Take a look at the CSS child selector `>`

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp
- http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/